# <input> linking to image does not display the jpg

Tags: html, css, image

Can anyone tell me why the following code displays an image:

```
<td width='100%';margin-top:20px; padding-top:40px;> <h1> Requests</td>
<td><img src= 'http://aisgrosurvey01/images/logo.jpg'  height='64'>
</td>
```

But further down in the same file, this does not?

```
<input type='text' id='myInput1' onkeyup='myFunction()' placeholder='Search by Department..'></br>
```

With my CSS file having this entry:

```
#myInput1{
    background-image: url('http://aisgrosurvey01/images/logo.jpg');  
    background-position: 10px 12px;  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    width: 36%;  
    font-size: 12px;  
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; 
    border: 1px solid #ddd;   
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 3px;         
    }
```

All the other formating from the CSS #myInput1 definition works.

Comment: Double quotes, no spaces.  `<img src="http://aisgrosurvey01/images/logo.jpg" height="64">`.

Comment: Not really reproducible. With a valid image URL (yours here won't work for anyone outside your system, no one here knows what `aisgrosurvey01` is supposed to point to), both versions show the image as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/aqszotcd/

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet that you have tested definitely reproduces the problem as at the moment your code appears to have no problem other than not looking as though it has a proper url to an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JayCravens the syntax of the input src attribute is OK. Single quotes are fine for example as is the space.

Comment: HTML?  It might run.  It's not going to validate.  https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input  I can't even believe it runs.  CSS looks great.

Comment: @JayCravens what error are you seeing in the validator? Only one I see (related to that img element) is lack of an alt attribute.

Comment: @AHaworth https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I9zuThwqme7AxsXAdKCgeQ7ELXV4cTU4/view?usp=sharing All those broken tags will have a large impact on the other code.  Go to literally any website and "View Source".

Comment: This is running on an internal company Linux server, not for use outside of the server. It must be something to do with the way the server is set up?! I have exactly the same code running on a different server that works no issue.

Answer (score -1):

The input tag has to be type = "image" like this:

```
<input type = 'image' src = 'http://aisgrosurvey01/images/logo.jpg' id = 'myInput1' onkeyup='myFunction()' placeholder='Search by Department..'>
```

You don't need to change the background-image thing in CSS.

Comment: I typed the code in exactly as you have here The image was not displayed (just the broken link icon), and my input box could no longer accept text input.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you wanted text input just a sec

Comment: Sorry it took so long. I just experimented a bit. What you can do is make an image and put the text input over that (use css to move the text input on top of image and make the image go to front layer also reshape it to be like the input).